# What is the reason for quasi-modals existing and why do they imply different meaning than the modals themselves?

Tags: etymology, modal-verbs, perfect-aspect, semi-modals, deontic-vs-epistemic

What I mean is - Why do we have collocations such as "be supposed to", "have to", "be able to"? I understand that modals are defective, but maybe more fundamentally, why are they defective, and why would the quasi-modal constructions imply different meaning, e.g. in the past:

I should have helped him.
x
I was supposed to help him.

You must have seen that movie.
x
You had to see that movie.

Is it necessary to consider these individually?

"Be supposed to" as a passive form of suppose, meaning "(We) supposed that X would do Y... =  X was supposed to do Y...?

"Have to" as former "have an obligation to", meaning "I had an obligation to see that movie"?

Why, then, does "I should have helped him." imply regret the way it does?

I don't necessarily see a reason for it having to imply regret, yet it seems like always does. And why don't we just use the perfect form modals for the meanings where we now tend to use the quasi-modal constructions?

To summarize, I am mostly interested in the origins of the quasi-modal constructions and why the meaning of them and modals themselves differs.

Comment: Your second pair aren't a *matching* pair. *You must have seen that movie* (I *currently believe* that you did see it) isn't exactly the same as *You had to see that movie* (it was *necessary in the past* for you to see it). The equivalent without ***must*** is *You **have to** have seen it* (where I and many others would pronounce the first ***have*** as ***haff***). Sometimes the implications of a modal verb imply ***regret*** that the  "counterfactual" situation referred to ***didn't*** happen. But other times it might imply ***relief***, or something completely different.

Comment: Why are you surprised that "should" and "to be supposed to" can have different meanings? Is there something that indicates that they should always have the same meaning?

Comment: The semantics of the modals are extremely complex. Though modals are often said to display alethic, epistemic and deontic modality in given contexts, the Wikipedia articles suggest many sub-categories. And I seem to remember an answer by @tchrist listing at least 16 usages of 'should'.

Comment: You ask a lot of questions about modals, whose syntax is every bit as complex as their semantics, with subcategories out the yingyang, as far as the ear can hear. Which one are you interested in getting answered here? Though generally it **is** necessary to consider modal expressions one at a time. They're all new idioms, since the loss of inflections over the last millennium.

Comment: [Related](https://youtu.be/0paNmu0bD1g)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan interesting question... I assume it's because in my native language they would be translated, at the surface, as the same sentence (though context would convey the difference in meaning).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Right... Thanks for pointing out them not matching. So could we say that modals in the perfect form always talk about counterfactual situations, but the exact stance of the speaker toward a particular situation may differ (regret/relief...)?

Comment: @JohnLawler I see... Well, what is the reason for them losing their inflection? I reckon that's a good place to start.

Comment: Old English was highly inflected, like German or Czech. After England was conquered by Norman French speakers, English was mostly spoken by illiterates and changed rapidly into many dialects. When these came together into Middle English, most of the inflections had been lost over the centuries. From Middle to Modern English  grammatical change has been in syntax, not inflection. Modern English grammar is syntax and constructions; the inflections don't really matter much any more. [There are only about 8 of them left anyway.](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf)

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the original question was generated because your native language has fully inflected modal auxiliary verbs that can be adapted to any situation where English hasta use quasi-modals. They **are** a very kludgy phenomenon, but then English syntax is notoriously kludgy.

Comment: @JohnLawler You are spot on, my question was fundamentally generated because I am Czech, and modality seems more complicated in English than in my native language. Although I might just be biased because of how natural inflections seem to me. Thank you for the provided information.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I'll be hanging on to that link about the difference between derivational and inflectional morphemes - a concept largely opaque to me until I just leafed through your brilliant summary. Main takeaway being that inflectional morphemes are more "generic" (hence *brother -> brothers*, not *brothership*) AND more tightly bound to the root word (hence ***chillier***, not ***chillery***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. It seems to be universal that inflections occur on word margins, while derivations are more interior. Most languages I know are suffixing, but prefixing language families like Mayan and Bantu work the same way. And it makes sense; the inflections connect the words, and the derivations expand them, so those are the appropriate places. One can see how it's a natural development that's probly occurred multiple times.

Comment: @JohnLawler: *Abso-fucking-lutely!* Which I think I now have the confidence to say is a *derivational* infix (you can't get any closer to the root word than being *inside* it! :) As opposed to *I say tomAHto he **says** say tomAYto* where that extra /s/ serves no real purpose. I think linguists usually say that language evolution is like evolution in general (always just trying to adapt to current circumstances, but not really "progressing"). But it ***is*** tempting for me to see English discarding inflectional morphemes as "advancement" (AAVE ***be*** a *very* advanced dialect, then?! :).

Comment: New languages like AAVE often generalize and regularize trends that aren't major in their source languages. Like AAVE totally remodeled _be_ and got rid of the scrap. Or the earlier lowerclass generalization of _ain't_ from _I'm not_ to being the standard present tense  negative - _I ain't, you ain't, he/she/it ain't, we ain't, they ain't_